# Classes not linking properly

Tags: c++, xcode, class, hyperlink, header

I have created a simple class with header file(.h), class implementation file (.cpp), and main file (.cpp).

There seems to be no errors until I try linking (building) in x-code where I get this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "bbq::bbq(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >)", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

And Here is my code:

```
int main()

{

bbq barbeque ("coleman", "101a");


barbeque.loadCoals(); // print output
```

The header file:

```
class bbq
{
private:
string brand, model;



public:
bbq (string brand, string model);
void loadCoals();}
```

And function definitions:

```
void bbq::loadCoals()
{

cout<<"Loading Coleman Grill 101A with coals!";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write bbq::bbq(string brand, string model); implementation in the .cpp file.

You have to implement it:

```
bbq::bbq(string brand, string model) {
   this->brand = brand;
   this->model = model;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I simply wrote inside the .cpp file, and it works.
    bbq::bbq(string brand, string model)
    { }
but what would I place(if anything) inside the function brackets, As my other functions are defined separately. @Pierre-Emmanuel-Lallemant

Comment: I've modified my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, however when I output(<<brand<<model; in the next functions loadcoals() the strings do not output as what I put here:
bbq barbeque ("coleman", "101a")

they are instead empty strings.
@Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant

Comment: std::cout << brand << " " << model << std::endl; ??

Comment: #include "File.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bbq::bbq(string brand, string model){
    brand=brand;
    model=model;
   
}
void bbq ::loadCoals()
{
    
    cout<<"Loading" << brand<<"Grill"<< model<< "with coals!";
    
}

and no output for the strings are generated.